# PHP mailer throws error in php 7 when tried send mail

Tags: phpmailer, php-7.0

I'm trying to send mail using PHP Mailer but I'm getting an error.
Kindly check my code let me know the fix.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

try {
    //Server settings
   $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx ';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxx', 'shiva');

    $mail->addAddress('siva.sing.sivan@gmail.com', 'SP');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('senthil.mca2008@gmail.com', 'SK');     // Add a recipient
    //\\$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('opensourcesivaprakash@gmail.com', 'Information');


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Test mail form SP';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message  <b>From SP!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }else{
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

**My Error:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

Please correct my code to fix the issue.

Comment: have you allowed gmail to connect with less secure app ?

Comment: Did you bother reading the troubleshooting guide to diagnose your issue like I suggested (since it addresses exactly how to diagnose this, especially on GoDaddy)? We can't correct your code because it's not a code problem; it's a network problem.

Comment: @NirmalDey yes I did.

Comment: @Synchro If it's network problem means at least should work on Localhost right.

Comment: No. You could have network issues (possibly different ones) in both places, but it's more likely to work on a consumer broadband connection as they don't usually block outbound SMTP like hosting companies often do.

Comment: @Synchro  and Nirmal Dey, thanks for your reply with patience.

finally solved that with the technical setting,

$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey @shiva use this `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and use port as `$mail->Port = 587` that's it!

Tell me it worked for you, if not then make sure to enable "**Less Secure Apps**" in your account settings, Thanks!

Let me know it worked for you or not?

Comment: That's Great. yesterday I have updated those settings after further research. Everything fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

upgrade the php version to 7.2.x and try it has inbuilt openssl 1.1.1